# php function file_exists not working

Tags: php, file-exists, configuration-files

i am trying to check a file to a certain location if the file does not exist. however the file_exist always returns false..

function added for check file exist

```
$file_path = "myconfigfile.config";
private function LoadFile( $file_path ) {
    $contents = '';
    if(file_exists($file_path)) {
        $handle = fopen( $file_path, "r" );
        while( !feof( $handle ) ) {
            $contents .= fread( $handle, 8192 );
        }
        @fclose( $handle );
    } 
    return $contents;
}
```

both files are exist in same folder but still not give proper output

please help me on this

Comment: The current working dir is not the current working dir you think it is. *Always* use relative paths to the current dir in PHP: `__DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/file'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your `$file_path` variable (currently "myconfigfile.config") is the absolute or relative path (relative to the script file being executed).

With your current configuration, there should be a file named `myconfigfile.config` in the same path as your php file for the function to return true.

Comment: but my myconfigfile.config file is in same directory where LoadFile() file saved...

Comment: Then are you running the file from a different directory?

Comment: no i have added both files in same directory...